# HTML helper application Notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++, helper

Would like to use Notepad++ as HTML helper application, to open some of my pages in the browser via Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like in notepad++ go to *Run->Launch in Chrome*